# Passing object between view controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a strange issue. I am trying to pass an object from `ViewControllerA` to `CreateInvitationViewController`.

In `ViewControllerA` I have following code:

```
func btnPassedRequestTouched(sender:UIButton!)
{
    print("button passed request touched")
    // pass request
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("createInvitationSegue", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "createInvitationSegue" {
        let createInvitationView = segue.destinationViewController as! CreateInvitationViewController
        let invitation = invitations[self.carousel.currentItemIndex]
        createInvitationView.invitation = invitation
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint on this line: `createInvitationView.invitation = invitation`, and I can see that this object exists.

In `ViewControllerB` I have the following code:

```
class CreateInvitationViewController: UIViewController {

    var invitation = Invitation()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // if invitation is set, then use it to populate fields
        if let _ = self.invitation.id {
            invitationText.hidden = false
            invitationText.text = self.invitation.note
        }
    }
```

I am using `Show` action on the segue that I made and it looks like this:
[image: Show action]
This is the error that I am getting:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MyProject.CreateInvitationViewController 0x156365810> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key postRequest.'
```

Do you have some suggestion why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's telling you it cannot find `postRequest`. That means that you either have some code that is trying to set `postRequest` or, more likely, you have some control in your storyboard that is trying to connect to an outlet called `postRequest`, but no such outlet exists (e.g. maybe you had some outlet with that name in the past, removed the outlet from the code, but neglected to update the storyboard accordingly).